# Simply MySQL Partition on One Column (groupID)

Tags: mysql, database, database-partitioning

I have a large-ish table (over 10 million rows). I have the following columns; 
`rowId`, `groupId` and `textString`. The ID's are both `ints` and `textString` is a simple `varchar`. I only have a maximum of 50 groupId's at a time which are stored in another table (possibly not of interest), but the groupID's are NOT sequential (rowId is AUTO_INCREMENT and the PRIMARY KEY).

What I would like to do, is to partition my table on these groupID's. I know what the list of groupIDs are (IE. 2342, 5251, 1591, 5915 etc etc).

How do I do this in MySQL?

Ammends: Running version 5.5.23

Thanks!